# How can i pass template throught slot to a child component Vue 3

Tags: vuejs3, vite

I need to pass to templates to a child component inside a parent component and I don't know how, something like this:

Parent:

```
<EasyTable :headers="headers" :url="url">
      <template v-slot:default>
        <template v-slot:item-is_admin="{ is_admin }">
          <Icon icon="mdi:check" v-if="is_admin" color="green" width="30" />
          <Icon icon="mdi:close" v-if="!is_admin" color="red" width="30" />
        </template>
        <template v-slot:item-id="{ id }">
          <button
            class="btn btn-error btn-xs text-white"
            @click="axios.delete(`${url}/${id}/`).then(() => router.go(0))"
          >
            Eliminar
          </button>
        </template>
      </template>
    </EasyTable>
```

Child:

```
    <EasyDataTable
    class="table-dark table-striped"
    buttons-pagination
    :headers="headers"
    :items="items"
    v-model:server-options="serverOptions"
    :server-items-length="serverItemsLength"
    :loading="loading"
    rows-per-page-message="Filas por pestaña">
     <slot />
   </EasyDataTable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no slot fallback in Vue, you should add it yourself:

[VUE SFC PLAYGROUND](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

```
  <EasyDataTable>
     <template v-for="(child, name) in $slots" #[name]="props">
        <Component :is="child" v-bind="props"/>
     </template>
  </EasyDataTable>
```